# Image Not rendering in Angular js senitize using (ng-bind-html)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

I am new to AngularJS, I am developing a **single page application using AngularJS**.
I have a `textarea` field, using this I am inserting some text with image.
 It is inserting into the table successfully and when I fetching the record, it is working fine for textarea, image is also rendering.
However, when I render it using  `ng-bind-html`

1. `image` is **not rendering**, only `html` and `text` are **rendering**.

[image]

In the above pic, red mark circle is an image.

when I try to render this using `ng-bind-html` image is not rendering.

Comment: Are you directly passing image data to `ng-bind-html` like ng-bind-html="imageData" ?

Comment: You need to pass it through $sce.trustAsHtml in your controller/link function. It tells Angular it's safe to parse the HTML.